# Using a spread operator while inside the variable that is being defined

Tags: javascript

I have an object that holds sub-objects. Some of these sub objects want to inherit from other sub objects, like below:

```
const actions = {
    global: {
        name: 'Global',
        setActionSet: (socket, newActionSet) => {
            sockets.actions = newActionSet;
        }
    },

    unregisteredSocket: {
        ...this.global,
        name: 'Unregistered',
        register: (socket, newActionSetName) => {
            socket.actions.setActionSet(socket, actionGroups[newActionSetName]);
        }
    },

    registeredSocket: {
        ...this.global,
        name: 'registered',
        setActionSet: (socket, newActionSet) => { /* something different from when it is unregistered */ },
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to have both `registeredSocket` and `unregisteredSocket` to inherit the default `setActionSet`, and overwrite `setActionSet` within `registeredSocket`. However, when I run the program, `unregisteredSocket` does not inherit from `global` like I thought it would - none of `global`'s members are unpacked into `unregisteredSocket`'s. `registeredSocket` has `setActionSet`, but it is the one that was redefined.

This causes calling `socket.actions.setActoinSet` in the `register` of `unregisteredSocket` to fail, as `setActionSet` has not been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `this` does not refer to the `actions` object, it refers to `window`.
That's why the spread operator does nothing, because `this.global` is `undefined`.

This does what you want:

```
const global = {
    name: 'Global',
    setActionSet: (socket, newActionSet) => {
        sockets.actions = newActionSet;
    }
};

const actions = {
    global,
    unregisteredSocket: {
        name: 'Unregistered',
        register: (socket, newActionSetName) => {
            socket.actions.setActionSet(socket, actionGroups[newActionSetName]);
        },
        ...global
    },

    registeredSocket: {
        name: 'registered',
        setActionSet: (socket, newActionSet) => { /* something different from when it is unregistered */
        },
        ...global
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the order matters when you define several times the same property of an object (only the last one counts).